# Cube roots answers

Tags: arithmetic

So I am in a middle of a problem and I got stuck at cube root of $8$. I know the answer is is $2$ but my book is showing a positive and negative 2. I thought that cube roots had only one answer. Please confirm which one would be correct and thanks

Comment: What is $(-2)^3$? There's your answer.

Comment: you gotta use complex numbers

Comment: Are you sure you haven't done something *else* wrong, causing you to think that the answer must be a cube root of 8 when it can actually be something else?

Answer (score 8):

$-2$ isn't a cube root of $8$. If you're sure your book's claiming it is, then that's a typo. You're right that numbers only have one cube root, as long as we're sticking to real numbers. If you allow imaginary numbers, they have three (except for $0.$)

Answer (score 3):

No, $-2$ is not cube root of $8$,

You can try $$(-2)(-2)(-2)=(4)(-2)=-8\neq8$$

And ,$$x^3=8$$
$$x^3-8=0$$
$$(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)=0$$

$$x=2,-1\pm i\sqrt3$$

As $x^3-8=0$ is a cubic polynomial it has 3 roots out of which two are <strike>*unfortunately*</strike> complex

Comment: Whether it's "unfortunately" depends on what you want them for, I think.